# Using Array and get-childitem to find filenames with specific ids

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

In the most basic sense, I have a SQL query which returns an array of IDs, which I've stored into a variable `$ID`. I then want to perform a `Get-childitem` on a specific folder for any filenames that contain any of the IDs in said variable (`$ID`) There are three possible filenames that could exist:

- `$ID.xml`
- `$ID_input.xml`
- `$ID_output.xml`

Once I have the results of `get-childitem`, I want to output this as a text file and delete the files from the folder. The part I'm having trouble with is filtering the results of `get-childitem` to define the filenames I'm looking for, so that only files that contain the IDs from the SQL output are displayed in my `get-childitem` results.

I found another way of doing this, which works fine, by using `for-each ($i in $id)`, then building the desired filenames from that and performing a remove item on them:

```
# Build list of XML files
$XMLFile = foreach ($I in $ID)
        {
          "$XMLPath\$I.xml","$XMLPath\$I`_output.xml","$XMLPath\$I`_input.xml"
        }

# Delete XML files
$XMLFile | Remove-Item -Force
```

However, this produces a lot of errors in the shell, as it tries to delete files that don't exist, but whose IDs do exist in the database. I also can't figure out how to produce a text output of the files that were actually deleted, doing it this way, so I'd like to get back to the `get-childitem` approach, if possible.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. If you require more info, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all `*.xml` files with `Get-ChildItem` to minimize the number of files to test and then use regex to match the filenames. It's faster than a loop/multiple test, but harder to read if you're not familiar with regex.

```
$id = 123,111

#Create regex-pattern (search-pattern)
$regex = "^($(($id | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'))(?:_input|_output)?$"

$filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\users\frode\Desktop\test" -Filter "*.xml" | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $regex }

#Save list of files
$filesToDelete | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-File "deletedfiles.txt" -Append

#Remove files (remove -WhatIf when ready)
$filesToDelete | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/dS2dJ5/2

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This one worked great. There was one additional thing I had to change though, for reference, if anyone else does a similar thing: $ID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id. I had to do this because the output of my SQL query, which was stored in variable $ID, was of type object, whereas I needed it as an array of strings.

Comment: That's why I added a sample `$id`, so you would know how it's value should be like. I would probably have added it like `$id = $sqlresults | select-object -expand id` as the variable-name itself says it's just IDs, but this is just details :-) Good luck "Powershelling"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clear
$ID = "a", "b", "c"
$filesToDelete = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$files = Get-ChildItem e:\
foreach ($I in $ID)
    {
      ($files | Where-object { $_.Name -eq "$ID.xml" }).FullName | ForEach-Object { $filesToDelete.Add($_) }
      ($files | Where-object { $_.Name -eq "$ID_input.xml" }).FullName | ForEach-Object { $filesToDelete.Add($_) }
      ($files | Where-object { $_.Name -eq "$ID_output.xml" }).FullName | ForEach-Object { $filesToDelete.Add($_) }
    }
$filesToDelete | select-object -Unique | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item $_ -Force }
```